# TypeError: Object of type Message is not JSON serializable | discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating autovc command for my discord bot but I ran into some error.
Code:

```
@client.command()
async def autovc(ctx):
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author
    await ctx.send("Please enter the channel name you want to create?")
    c_name= await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    await ctx.send("What would be the channel user limit?")
    c_limit= int((await client.wait_for('message', check=check)).content)
    await ctx.send("Please Enter the Category ID in which tha channel will be created.")
    guild = client.get_guild(852866665371926588)
    ctg= discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=(int((await client.wait_for('message', check=check)).content)))
    await guild.create_voice_channel(name= c_name, category= ctg, user_limit= c_limit)
```

Error:

> File
> "C:\Users\illus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 85, in wrapped
> ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)   File "d:\BOT\test.py", line 30, in autovc
> await guild.create_voice_channel(name= c_name, category= ctg, user_limit= c_limit)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\illus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py",
> line 987, in create_voice_channel
> data = await self.*create_channel(name, overwrites, ChannelType.voice, category, reason=reason, **options)   File
> "C:\Users\illus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py",
> line 156, in request
> kwargs['data'] = utils.to_json(kwargs.pop('json'))   File "C:\Users\illus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py",
> line 328, in to_json
> return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':'), ensure_ascii=True)   File
> "C:\Users\illus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json_*init**.py",
> line 234, in dumps
> return cls(   File "C:\Users\illus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py",
> line 199, in encode
> chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)   File "C:\Users\illus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py",
> line 257, in iterencode
> return _iterencode(o, 0)   File "C:\Users\illus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py",
> line 179, in default
> raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
>
> TypeError: Object of type Message is not JSON serializable
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\illus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py",
> line 939, in invoke
> await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)   File "C:\Users\illus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 863, in invoke
> await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)   File "C:\Users\illus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 94, in wrapped
> raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: TypeError: Object of type Message is not JSON serializable

Comment: What's the traceback for the initial exception?

Comment: Updated! I'd put whole terminal output there.

Comment: I'd recommend going for inputting the required arguments (channel name, category ID, user limit) using the command directly, like so: `async def autovc(ctx, c_name: str, c_categid: int, c_limit: int):`

Answer (score 2):

I think it is happening because you are trying to name your vc with `message` object and not `string`. Instead of putting `c_name` as `name` parameter try putting `c_name.content` so you get the actual contents of the message. Like this:

```py
await guild.create_voice_channel(name=c_name.content, category=ctg, user_limit=c_limit)
```

I haven't tested it but I'm pretty sure that's the problem.